# DivX cannot compress my movie

Tags: video

I have a 30GB movie that I need to compress with VirtualDub using DivX codec (latest version).
However, VirtualDub (or rather DivX) complains that

```
[i] Dub: Output (compression) format is: RGB888.
[E] Error: Video compression error: The source image format is not acceptable.
    (error code -2)
```

BS Player shows the following details for the uncompressed movie:

The resolution is 1388x1040.
Surface type: RGB32
The color depth is (I think) 48 bit - DivX supports only 24/32 bits.

I think I need a VirtualDub filter to decrease the color depth but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to resize my movie in order to compress it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with WMV files (I have the WMV plugin).  Other WMV files recoded in VirtualDub, but these were High Resolution 900 x 504 files.

I resolved this problem simply by selecting a Microsoft WMV codec.  So this problem is just a codec problem.  Having said this, the solution for each user is different depending on the INPUT file.  You have to find the right codec for your input file & get VirtualDub to recongize that codec so it is in the list of codecs available to VirtualDub.